# Using Google Sheets API with Node

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, google-api, google-sheets

I am trying to load one of my google sheets with node. I am able to get my access tokens from google but when I try and load the sheet I get the error:

> Error: No access to that spreadsheet, check your auth.spreadsheet

Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

CLIENT_ID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
CLIENT_SECRET = "MY_SECRET";
REDIRECT_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/oauth/callback";


var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);

var google = require('googleapis');
var GoogleSpreadsheets = require('google-spreadsheets');
var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);

var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'online', 
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' 
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(url);
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/oauth/callback', function (req, res) {
var code = req.param('code');

    GoogleSpreadsheets({
    key: 'MY_SHEET_KEY',
    auth: oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if(!err) {
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    }
    console.log(tokens); //this prints my tokens as an array
})
}, function(err, spreadsheet) {
    console.log(err + "spreadsheet");
});

res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: You've enabled the Google Sheets API in the Google Dev Console?

Comment: yes @colonelsanders

Comment: Google published a quickstart for the new v4 sheets API that includes node code for the authorization.  I suggest you give that code a try:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs#prerequisites